# Setting config values in unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

No matter what I try, I can't seem to set/change config values in unit tests:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    Config::set('demo.enabled', true);
}
```

It is always staying as `false`. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's not even set in runtime?

Comment: I figured out that it is being set now, but for whatever reason my middleware being called in the unit test isn't picking up on the changes.

Comment: You will want to set the config values in your `phpunit.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code after setting the config value

```
Artisan::call('config:clear');
```

This will clear the config cache and should then allow your new config option value to be used.